# Java: If-else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I made a twitch irc bot.
I have setup a little "system" to turn itself on whenever the stream is going online and should turn off when the stream isnt online anymore.

im using the following code:

```
if (TwitchStatus.isstreamlive && multistartprepare == false && multistartprepare2 == false){
    livemode = true;
    multistartprepare = true;
    startedAt = DateTime.now();
    startup();
}else{

    if (TwitchStatus.isstreamlive == false && multistartprepare){
      livemode = false;
      multistartprepare = false;
      multistartprepare2 = false;
      TTmsg.cancel();
      TTmsg.purge(); 
    }
}
```

isstreamlive is a boolean which is either true when a stream is live or false when the stream is offline.

isstreamlive gets updated every 5 secons by making a JSON request and holds the right value the whole time.

the problem now is that the startup() Method will activate a timer for a greeting message in the irc chat.  Somehow it happens the timer got executed 2 or 3 times when i start my bot so i guess something is wrong with my if else statement.

the booleans multistartprepare and multistartprepare2 are false on start and are there for the bot to start only once a time, til the stream is over and he can get offline.

is there something wrong above? Guess the code gets executed to many times.

greetings and sorry for bad english :D

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you use your `livemode` variable in the if as well

```
if (TwitchStatus.isstreamlive &&
            !multistartprepare &&
            !multistartprepare2  &&
            !livemode) {
```

Comment: Why would that change anything? :confused:

Answer (score 0):

You might be able work around this by setting up a timeout that prevents your bot from sending the message if it's been sent in the past few seconds.

```
long lastSent = 0;
...
if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastSent > 1000*5) { // 5 seconds elapsed
    ...
    // send message
    lastSent = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

You might have something wrong with your setup method, or the server might be sending you multiple went-online messages, but it's hard to tell based on the info you have so far.